# SQL islands - advanced

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There's a table of employment:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employment (EmployeeName VARCHAR(100), EmploymentStart DATETIME, EmploymentEnd DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('John','2013-08-01','2013-08-07')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('John','2013-09-08','2014-05-30')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('John','2014-05-31','2014-09-29')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('John','2014-09-30','2015-09-17')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('John','2015-09-18','2015-10-28')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('John','2015-11-29','2015-12-15')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('Kelly','2014-07-19','2014-12-30')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('Kelly','2014-12-31','2015-03-22')
INSERT INTO #Employment VALUES ('Kelly','2015-04-02','2015-09-18')
```

I need to select employees (together with each record of employment) who between two declared dates:

1. Don't have contiguous employment record i.e. employment record has ended and there's no following employment or employment has ended and the following employment record is not contiguous to the ended one (must be at least one day gap).

or

2. Have 12 months contiguous employment i.e. island of the first contiguous employment record and the employment record ending between the declared dates is 12 months (the 12 months period falls into the ending record span); employee can have records of employment before but none of them can be 12 months contiguously; if employee has following contiguous contracts that would qualify for 12 months contiguous employment in another declared dates they shouldn't be selected. Example: employees get rewards for first 12 months contiguous employment; each employee can get the reward only once.

Because one employee can have records fulfilling both conditions I need to have a SetId assigned to each selected record spliting records by conditions.

Declared dates:

```
DECLARE @Date_1 DATETIME = '2014-09-14', @Date_2 DATETIME = '2014-09-21'
```

should return

```
SetId; EmployeeName; EmploymentStart; EmploymentEnd
1; John; 2013-09-08; 2014-05-30  -- Condition 2 fulfilled
1; John; 2014-05-31; 2014-09-29  -- Condition 2 fulfilled
```

and

```
DECLARE @Date_1 DATETIME = '2015-09-15', @Date_2 DATETIME = '2015-09-21'
```

should return

```
SetId; EmployeeName; EmploymentStart; EmploymentEnd    
1;John;2014-05-31;2014-09-29  -- Condition 2 fulfilled
1;John;2014-09-30,2015-09-17  -- Condition 2 fulfilled
2;John;2015-09-18;2015-10-28  -- Condition 1 fulfilled
3;Kelly;2015-04-02;2015-09-18  -- Condition 1 fulfilled
```

Any help much appreciated.

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: Can you please tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried CTE to find islands (and succeded) but because there's this 12 month period condition I supose a decent cursor will be required.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1):

for the second condition you can try using LEAD and LAG analytic statements for connecting each record with its next one and then filter all those who have a gap of more then 1 day and by that recalculate the start date and the end date that were not interupted and then check if the Declared start date smaller then your end date and the Declared end date is bigger then your end date(thats if i understood what you want to do)
you can read about lead and lag here:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html

The first condition i didn't quite understand . i guess you can apply it there also again, i didn't understand

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `union all` between the queries that return the conditions.

Assuming the records are not complicated -- with nested periods and complex overlaps -- then you can identify the first using `lead()` and basic logic:

```
select e.*, 'First Condition'
from (select e.*,
             lead(EmploymentStart) over (partition by EmployeeName order by EmploymentStart) as next_es
      from #Employment e
      where EmploymentStart <= @Date_2 and EmploymentEnd >= @Date_1
     ) t
where next_es > dateadd(day, 1, EmployementEnd);
```

The second is a gaps-and-islands problem, which can be solved using cumulative sums.  In SQL Server 2012+, this is essentially:

```
select e.EmployeeName, 'Second Condition'
from (select e.*, sum(PeriodStart) over (partition by EmployeeName order by EmploymentStart) as grp
      from (select e.*,
                   (case when lag(EmployementEnd) over (partition by EmployeeName order by EmploymentStart) < datedd(day, -1, EmployeeStart
                         then 1 else 0 end) as PeriodStart
            from #Employment e
            where EmploymentStart <= @Date_2 and EmploymentEnd >= @Date_1
           ) e
     ) e
group by EmployeeName, grp
having dateadd(day, min(EmployeeStart), max(EmployeeStart)) >= 365;
```

You may need to modify this query to handle 1-year periods that span the date span specified.  The final query is a union of these (with the appropriate columns) that chooses only one row per employee for the second (using `row_number()`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, apologies for the late reply but I had a tough week start. Thank you for the hints! First one works perfect but second doesn't - if you test it over the declared dates provided in the question you won't get the result sets as expected.